# How to format string with numbers and decimals?

Tags: unix, awk, string-formatting

My text.csv file looks like this. I want to truncate the floating point numbers using the awk command.

```
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011569,1.1234873687000001
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011584,0.8789456464999999
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011587,0.4543572142000001
```

I am doing this:

```
awk '{ FS = "," ; printf(sprintf("%s,%d,%.10f\n",$1,$2,$3))}' text.csv
```

However, the "%s" is formatting the first column in a weird way

```
ZAR,0,0.0000000000
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011584,0.8789456465
8ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011587,0.4543572142
```

Where as I would like something like

```
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011569,1.1234873687
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011584,0.8789456465
ZAR Spot Up 8%,10011587,0.4543572142
```

I believe it has something to do with the '8' or the '%' sign. Any idea what the correct command is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `FS` much earlier in your script; the first line of input has already been read and parsed by the time you assign it.

In addition, the double `printf` is obviously superfluous.

```
awk -F, '{ printf("%s,%d,%.10f\n",$1,$2,$3)}' text.csv
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If I wanted to replace the floats in the file with the concatenated version, is the best way just to pipe the output of the awk command to a new file? The file is quite large (3.5 million rows)

Comment: Not sure I understand your follow-up question, but yeah, saving to a new file and then replacing the original file with that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are using data in the `printf format, data` format argument location and that data contains a formatting character (`%`). Just don't do that, use `printf format, data` as per the synopsis.

Specifically in your case you are doing (note `printf` is getting one argument):

```
printf sprintf("%s,%d,%.10f\n",$1,$2,$3)
```

so the output of `sprintf` which includes `%` characters is the first arg to `printf` and that's where the format arg goes. If you changed it to:

```
printf "%s", sprintf("%s,%d,%.10f\n",$1,$2,$3)
```

then you wouldn't have the problem but of course the sprintf is superfluous since you could just write:

```
printf "%s,%d,%.10f\n",$1,$2,$3
```

and in this case since you really only want to modify the 3rd field your whole script could just be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=sprintf("%.10f",$3)} 1' text.csv
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the 1 mean at the end of the script?

Comment: An awk script is  series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements where the default action is to print the current record so when you write a constant non-zero, non-null condition like `1` or `"foo"` that is a true condition and so invokes the default action of printing the current record. It is a VERY common awk idiom that's not only brief but forces you to understand the very basic idea/structure of the awk language.